# Cpp/C++ Word counter from another file using map's

Tags: c++

I've been given task in school to write a program that count's words used in file, but words may only start with upper/lower case or "_" and include only letters and numbers 0-9.
For example I have file like this:

```
#include <map>
int main(){
   map<string, int> vector
   int vector1;
return 0;
}
```

And this is expected output:
include : 1
map : 2
int : 3
string : 1
vector : 1
vector1 : 1
return : 1

This is what i've got already but it counts every line of the code not only words:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

typedef map<string, int> identifiers;

void countWords(istream &in, identifiers& w){
  string s;
  while(in >> s){
    ++w[s];
  }
}

int main()
{
fstream file;
file.open("test.txt",ios::in);
if(file){
   identifiers w;
   countWords(file, w);
   for(identifiers::iterator p = w.begin(); p!=w.end();++p){
       cout<<p->first<<" : "<<p->second<<endl;
   }
   
}
 
else{
   cout<<"Error opening the file"<<endl;
   exit(1);
}
file.close();
return 0;
}
```

Comment: You did not ask a question. I guess you should write a function isWord(const std::string&) that checks the first and other characters according to the requirements. What issues with it do you get?

Comment: Yeah, my bad, my issue was that program would only count “structure” of letters, but I’ve managed to work it out with function that scan all letters available in my question and adding them into map as words, but thanks